# JavaScript Uncaught ReferenceError: ListMgr is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a huge problem with my javascript code, basically I can't find why is my ListMgr not defined...

I have ListMgr.js loaded (it looks like this for now):

```js
var ListMgr = {
    maxItems : 6,
    currentItems : 1,

    initialize : function (_maxItems, _currentItems) {
        if (_maxItems === undefined) { 
            _maxItems = 6;
        } 
        if (_currentItems === undefined) {
            _currentItems = 1;
        } 
        this.maxItems = _maxItems;
        this.currentItems = _currentItems;
    };
};
```

Then in my html file I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mgr = new ListMgr();
    mgr.initialize(10, 1);
});
```

And it throws

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ListMgr is not defined.

Any help will be appreciated - I believe everything should be correct here, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: First: you can't `new` an object, only a function. Secondly, show the code where you are including `ListMgr.js` and whether there were any errors in the Network tab loading it. Easiest way, put an `alert` statement in `ListMgr.js` and make sure it gets called before your code that uses it

Comment: exactly, I've made change using Object.create but it is still undefined. mgr.js containing my object is loaded via assetic in twig template and it's correctly loaded (checked with Chrome dev tools). Still, it's not defined - is it something with scope? Those two are contained in different <script> tags.

Comment: Are you not going to follow my suggestion?

Comment: I did solve it Juan : ) I copied my assetic code for css and did forget to change "<link ... " to "<script ... " :) that's thanks to your "show the code where you are including it" suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

`ListMgr` is an object and not a function so you can't invoke it as `new ListMgr()`. You probably want to use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mgr = Object.create(ListMgr);
    mgr.initialize(10, 1);
});
```

Comment: This is correct, but it doesn't match the error the OP is getting. If `ListMgr` was defined and you call `new` on it, you get the "ListMgr is not a function" instead of "ListMgr is not defined"

Comment: @JuanMendes exactly, I've made change using Object.create but it is still undefined. mgr.js containing my object is loaded via assetic in twig template and it's correctly loaded (checked with Chrome dev tools). Still, it's not defined - is it something with scope? Those two are contained in different <script> tags.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `new`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ListMgr.initialize(10, 1);
    console.log(ListMgr.maxItems);
    console.log(ListMgr.currentItems);
});
// 10
// 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solve it eventually, my assetic code was incorrect and the file was not actually injected in  tag. Silly me.

Thanks for any help anyway!